# How to render each properties value without map and for loop in the react?

Tags: json, reactjs, object, render

I has the question about render the value of properties in the Object.
Here is my Object, which is the format of JSON

```
Object {
    "C": { more nest JSON   },
    "B": "b"
    "A": { more nest JSON  },
}
```

I save this object in the state, like this:

```
this.setState({
    Object: Ojbect
})
```

And I want to render the JSON value by order A, B,C. But none of them can be rendered, and no syntax error.
Any idea how to fix it?
this is what I write

```
render(){
    return(
    //also try :  <p> A: <pre>{JSON.Stringify(this.state.Obejct["A"], null,2)} <pre> <p>
    <p> A: <pre>{JSON.Stringify(this.state.Obejct.A, null,2)} <pre> <p>
    <p> B: <pre>{JSON.Stringify(this.state.Obejct.B, null,2)} <pre> <p>
    <p> C: <pre>{JSON.Stringify(this.state.Obejct.C, null,2)} <pre> <p>
    )

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I close this question by myself.
Finally, I figure out that we can't render objects directly in the render.
So three solutions:

1. use map function to render the key /value
2. parse the value into the state, and render the state
3. use the JSON.stringify to parse the object(ex: JSON format), save it as the state, and render the state